# Can you transfer your applications like photoshop from your old mac to your new macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, time-machine, external-disk

Is it possible using a passport external hard drive and tome machine to transfer applications from my old macbook to my new macbook?

Please advise a safe way to do this if it is possible?

Comment: Are you looking to just transfer apps or all your files that way in addition to the apps?

Comment: All my files and apps. I back up my mac with Time Machine saving it to an external hard drive.

Comment: Yes, it is simple and safe to restore from Time Machine. I would de-authorize any Adobe or similar apps on your previous computer before wiping it. You can easily register the apps on your new setup then. In the case of Adobe CC, though, you may not even have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the Apple Migration Assistant (in /Applications/Utilities) will transfer documents, settings and Applications.

However some (most?) Applications transfer flawlessly and some do not. I would imagine, what with all the posts I see online, that Adobe applications may require more than just Migration Assistant. At the very least you will have to activate the applications again with Adobe. You *may* have to reinstall the apps or even call Adobe support to activate/authorize your Adobe applications on your new Mac.

But I would start with Migration assistant, unless someone here with specific experience with migrating Adobe apps says otherwise.

Comment: When I migrated Photoshop recently, everything migrated successfully, inc plugins & paths, but I did have to re-authorise.

Comment: Would doing a time machine restore eliminate the reauthorization? (ie do a time machine restore onto the new computer instead of using Migration Assistant